# How do I increase a counter by 1 for each repeated value?

Tags: sql, database, ms-access

As part of my course in university I have to make a database in Microsoft Access which is somewhat limiting me on what I'm trying to do. I have a table that has the information of whether a player in a team was present for a fixture or not using the values "P", "R", and "M" (Played, Reserves, Missed). I want to make a query that counts a value of 1 for each value of P or R and a separate one for M, so that when I make a report that prints off a membership card, it shows the amount of fixtures they've played in and the amount of fixtures that they have missed.

Sorry if this isn't clear, I'll try to explain myself further if you ask but I'm not very good with this stuff. Thank you.

Edit: I'll use screenshot links if that's okay, here is the [Fixture Attendance](http://puu.sh/8eTgC.png) entity that shows if a member of a team attended a game or not. I'm making a membership card based off [this one](http://puu.sh/8eTzk.png). I want to be able to display the No. of fixtures played by the member and the No. of fixtures missed based off the values in the above entity and use that information in a form I'm going to create. That will be a subform inside my Membership Card form.

I'm presumably really bad at explaining this - I understand Access is rarely used in the real world so I'm not sure why I'm doing this in the first place and don't feel like I'm getting any real knowledge of working with databases.

Comment: When explaining a question, it is helpful to include sample data and desired results.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Sorry about that, I updated the main body with what I think should be relevant.

Answer (score 1):

You should use the COUNT function.

http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/count-data-by-using-a-query-HA010096311.aspx

Answer (score 1):

I am guessing that you want something like this:

```
select playerid, sum(iif(fixture in ("P", "R"), 1, 0)) as NumPR,
       sum(iif(figure = "M", 1, 0)as NumM
from table t
group by playerid;
```

The key idea here is putting the conditional part (`iif()`) inside the `sum()`.

Answer (score 0):

`CASE WHEN` can be used to translate the codes into 1's and 0's. Then use `SUM` with a `GROUP BY` to sum them.

```
SELECT player_id, SUM(Played), SUM(Reserve), SUM(Missed)
FROM
(SELECT player_id,
  CASE WHEN present = 'P' THEN 1 ELSE 0 AS Played,
  CASE WHEN present = 'R' THEN 1 ELSE 0 AS Reserve,
  CASE WHEN present = 'M' THEN 1 ELSE 0 AS Missed
FROM fixtures)
GROUP BY player_id;
```

Comment: `CASE WHEN` is a construct that is supported in T-SQL but not in Access SQL.